# How do I run .map() starting from the second index onward?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I need to use `map` starting from the second index. I know how to use loop for with I start from 1 but I want to use `map` in this case.

Is there a correct way to do this with `map`?

I'm using JavaScript and ReactJS.

Comment: `.slice(1).map(...)`

Comment: If you think about it this doesn't make sense. `.map()` by definition runs on every element in an array. Thus it would make sense to remove the first element of the newly derived element afterwards.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just `slice` before you `map`:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const res = arr.slice(1).map(e => e * 2);
console.log(res);
```

Alternatively, use `shift` after mapping the full array:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const res = arr.map(e => e * 2);
res.shift();
console.log(res);
```